# understanding Jquery extend documentation example

Tags: jquery, json

I got this example from the jQuery Docs , for the extend function : [Jquery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)(the last example)

```
var defaults = { validate: false, limit: 5, name: "foo" };
var options = { validate: true, name: "bar" };
// Merge defaults and options, without modifying defaults
var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {
    var arr = [];
    $.each( obj, function(key, val) {
        var next = key + ": ";
        next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? printObj(val) : val;
        arr.push( next );
    });
    return "{ " + arr.join( ", " ) + " }";
};
$("#log").append("defaults -- " + printObj(defaults) + "");
$("#log").append("options -- " + printObj(options) + "");
$("#log").append("settings -- " + printObj(settings) + "");
```

on line 6 is the function ever being called ? i mean does the ternary operator ever evaluate to false ?? 
i did a console.log('function called'); inside the function and did't get any console.logs

also please have a look at line 6 again :

```
var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {
```

if u were a english teacher ,teaching Jquery how would the above statement really read out ?

"check printObj" if it is a a JSON type if it is than JSON.stringify it , else execute the function .

now a few more supplemetary but important questions :

is't JSON.stringify suppose to be taking an argument ??

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

now i call printObj like this :

```
 $( "#log" ).append( "defaults -- " + printObj( defaults ) + "" );
```

going back to line 6 , specifically the below line :

```
typeof JSON !== "undefined"
```

what am i checking here ??

if printObj itself is typeof JSON ??

or defaults is typeof JSON ??

the confusion continues as i read line 6 ahead :

```
JSON.stringify
```

now JSON.stringify what ??

if printObj itself is typeof JSON ??

or defaults is typeof JSON ??

i would really like to understand whats happening , because i am trying to build a small tiny pluggin of my own .

Thanks .

Tenali.

Comment: ternary operation `if/else`.

Comment: @Jai My question was't about the ternary operator .

Comment: it would be really helpful to know why was the question downvoted ? so maybe i can improve next time. if you look at the question , the code has quite a few things that might not be obvious to a newbie .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### See:

What you have here:

```
var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {};
```

Take `JSON.stringify` first:

It might be something like this:

```
JSON = {
          parse:function(args){},
          stringify:function(args){}
       };
```

so `stringify` is the method which is available in the `JSON` object. Hence `printObj` gets the `stringify` method from `JSON` object.

Now as you are using ternary operator `condition ? true : false ;` then if `typeof JSON !== "undefined"` if this returns `true` then your `var printObj` gets the `JSON.stringify` method `else` execute the custom function as applied in the else block.

taking forward:

```
typeof JSON !== "undefined"
```

***what am i checking here ??***

i would say an object which is already defined in the script apis available in the browsers which is said to be *ECMA Script*. This method `JSON.stringify()` is available in the modern browsers available today but if anyone is using older browser then it returns `undefined` in this case else block method will be assigned to `var printObj` to return the same output which `JSON.stringify()` does *(String representation of js object/serialising the js object)*.

***if printObj itself is typeof JSON ??***

No, `printObj` is a variable which is getting assigned a method either `JSON.stringify` or  the function from the else block.

It depends on browser you are using, its a simple check if `JSON` object is available in the browser when you run your scripts.

***or defaults is typeof JSON ??***

No, `defaults` as you can see in your code its a variable which holds a js object and if you do this `JSON.stringify(defaults)` it creates a string representation of your js object.

---

```
JSON.stringify
```

***now JSON.stringify what ??***

As you are assigning this method in your ternary operation if condition is `true` then it gets assigned to your `var printObj`. it is something like this:

```
var printObj = JSON = {
                  stringify:function(args){}
               };
```

when you do this:

```
printObj( defaults );
```

***if printObj itself is typeof JSON ??***

Again No, `printObj` is a variable which holds a method either `JSON.stringify()` or its fallback in the else block as you posted in your post.

***or defaults is typeof JSON ??***

No, `defaults` as you can see in your code its a variable which holds a js object and if you do this `JSON.stringify(defaults)` it creates a string representation of your js object.

---

So after this i just simply want to add that:

```
var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {};
```

you are assigning a method to your variable if `typeof JSON` is *`!== undefined`* which is `true` then assign the `JSON.stringify()` method else assign the custom function of the else block.

Comment: Note that `JSON.stringify` is a native JS function in modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify. The ternary here is being used to define a fallback function for older browsers which do not have the JSON functionality by default.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's what i wanted to continue as per questions in the post. and BTW thanks for the link.

Comment: @Jai Ironically all my assumptions got a "No" , but i guess thats just the way u learn ! . Thank you :)

Comment: Glad if this is been any help.

Comment: @Jai it did indeed . Thanks for being so elaborate and most of all , thanks for your time .

Answer (score 1):

> var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {
>   if u were a english teacher ,teaching Jquery how would the above statement really read out ?

If you bear in mind that `JSON` is an object which is built in to modern browsers, this code is checking to see if that object is available for use (it will return `undefined` in older browsers which do not implement it).

If `JSON` not available, a function is returned in the ternary to do the equivalent work of `JSON.stringify`. The ternary is used to assign a reference to either of these functions (whichever is needed) to the `printObj` variable. This variable is then used later in the code to serialise an object.

> is't JSON.stringify suppose to be taking an argument ??

Yes - assuming you want to invoke the function. This code is assigning the *reference* to the function to the variable.

Your confusion seems to stem from that fact that this code is dealing with the references to functions without invoking them directly. Here's a simple example:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    console.log(bar);
}

var Fuzz = Foo; // Note, the function reference of Foo is now assigned to Fuzz. Foo is not called.

Fuzz('lorem ipsum'); // This is now invoking the logic of the Foo function via the reference in Fuzz.
```